# Testing IDisposable and WCF client

Tags: c#, wcf, unit-testing, mocking

Usually I have client code similiar to something like this:

```
// SomeOtherServiceClient would be injected in actual code.
ISomeOtherService client = new SomeOtherServiceClient();
```

... so that I can mock the service for testing.  But now I have a WCF service that has the context mode set to `PerSession` and implements `IDisposable`.

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
public class SampleService : ISampleService, IDisposable
{
    public void SampleMethod() { ... }
    public void Dispose() { ... }
}
```

If I wish to put the client inside a `using` statement, is there still a way for me to mock the client for testing?

```
// SampleServiceClient would be injected in actual code.
using (var client = new SampleServiceClient())
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Juval Lowy explicitly recommends against the using statement on proxys. In the presence of a transport session, any service-side expection will fault the channel. Trying to dispse of the proxy when the channel is faulted throws a CommunicationObjectFaultedException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem, it is that `ISomeOtherService` is a WCF service contract, and does not implement `IDisposable` even though all implementing clients will. You can get around this by changing the using statement to something like this:

```
public void SampleMethod()
{
    //client was injected somehow
    using(this.client as IDisposable)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not solve the issue mentioned by Andrew above, the dispose method will throw an exception on a faulted channel. Use Juval`s method for safely closing proxies.